# JScrollPane does not work

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

Here is a code of a simple editor.

```
public class editor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        final JTextArea area = new JTextArea(20,120);
        JScrollPane scrollingResult = new JScrollPane(area,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        f.getContentPane().add(scrollingResult);
        ...
    }
}
```

This doesn't work. `JTextArea` is fine, so is the `Frame`, but `JScrollPane` is still disabled. Why could that be?

Comment: Could be a look and feel optimisation. Try putting lots of text in the box.

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have just created a `JTextArea` and added it to a `JScrollPane`. However I cannot see any text being added to your `JTextArea`. The scroll option activates only when you have something to scroll through.

Also I would suggest that you change your `HorizontalScrollBarPolicy` and `VerticalScrollBarPolicy` from being `JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS` & `JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS` to `HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED` and `VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED` respectively.

Comment: is it necessary for text to be present at compile-time?

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze - nope! but then why would you need an activated scroll bars to appear when you've nothing to scroll through?

Comment: i just copied this code to the new project, and it worked just fine. what could be wrong with this one?!

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze: It's difficult to guess but maybe the `size` of each component. If you need more insight do please consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) version of your code.

Comment: To the one who down-voted this answer: Care to explain why? :)

Comment: Thanks @kleopatra! But I'm still curious for the down-vote :( :'(

Comment: Generally it is most optimal to have the text area wrap on word, a vertical scroll-bar as needed, and a horizontal scroll-bar never.  +1 for your answer.

Comment: it turned out that i had `add(area)` in one of the following lines.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me, I can even type in the text area.

[image: Look at me]